# Count the number of repetitive values separated by commas

Tags: count, data-science, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have the set that looks something like :

| colA |
| --- |
| Nepal , India , USA |
| USA |
| India |
| USA |
| Nepal , India |
| USA |
| USA, Nepal |
| Nepal |
| Japan |

so I want the count as :

| COlB | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Nepal | 4 |
| India | 3 |
| USA | 5 |
| Japan | 4 |

Is there a way to do it, without going into the Tableau Prep and directly from Tableau Reader with the use of calculative fields or something similar within it.

Comment: Create a new field using split/custom split options in tableau desktop. And then use the aggregation on top of the field to get results.

Answer (score 1):

the following code solves your problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["a","b","a,b,c","d,d,e,f","a,e,t"], columns=['ColA'])

df2=pd.DataFrame(list(df['ColA'].str.split(','))).melt().dropna().groupby(['value']).agg('count')

df2 #show df2
```

The below code provides a solution that is shorter in terms of sintax and data transformation.

Considering the data frame i create in the example, just do the below.

```
df['ColA'].str.split(',').explode('ColA').value_counts()
```

The below topic solves a identical problem but with two columns instead of 1. [How can I count comma-separated values in my Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412077/how-can-i-count-comma-separated-values-in-my-dataframe)